# disability insurance on a car loan

Tags: insurance, disability

I have a car loan which i am the primary borrower and my daughter is the second . I recently became disabled. The bank put the disability insurance on the loan . My question is will they pay my car payments or try to go after my Daughter for the payments ?

Answer (score 4):

Check the policy paperwork. That should explain how the terms of the policy are triggered. It should define disabled, how long before payments start, what doctors proof is needed, and what it means to return to work.

Because there are two borrowers involved in the loan, the paperwork should also address what happens when only one is disabled.